# What is Les Claypool doing during this live show of Those Damned Blue Collar Tweekers?

Tags: technique, electric-bass-guitar

During live performances of Those Damned Blue Collar Tweekers, Les does something with his hand when playing the bass during the refrain that I don't understand.

You can pretty clearly see it right about at the 2:16 mark on this Youtube recording of a show at [Woodstock 94](https://youtu.be/LiQa8pIVPjI?t=136). Cross referencing this with online bass tabs, they claim each strum of his hand is only hitting the top two D and G strings on the instrument.

I'm new to bass, and I can't figure out what exactly he's doing. Is he doing a kind of open hand strum where he just hits the top two strings? Or is he doing some kind of glancing slap on the strings? Or is this just a showy way to pluck the two strings like most other bassists do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is strumming the strings with the tops of his fingernails, similarly to how a flamenco guitar player would strum.

[Here is a clip](https://youtu.be/6pL846H2Sl0?t=158) of a flamenco guitar player demonstrating this technique on an acoustic guitar.

This is mechanically similar to an aggressive strum with a pick, and might sound like a slap if the strings hit the fretboard hard enough.